# How might the recurrence relation for the gcd function be solved?

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Euclidean_division), the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of two numbers $a,b$ can be written
$$
r_k = r_{k-2}\mod{r_{k-1}}
$$
Is this recurrence relation solvable (as in has a non-recursive form specifying $r_k$) and if so, how might this recurrence relation be solved? I'm not asking for a proof of a solution - more like a sketch of what the most fruitful direction probably is. What techniques may apply to this relation? Should I decompose modulo into an algebraic series and solve? Apply the z-transform? Furthermore, what might be good sources to read more on recurrence relations?